# Wso2 ESB: Unable to download the Magento Connector .zip file

Tags: magento, connector, wso2-esb

I am not able to download the Magento connector from the below URL

https://github.com/wso2/esb-connectors/tree/master/magento

Could you please let me know how and where to download Magento Connector (.zip file) for WSO2 ESB.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please respond where to download Magento connector for Wso2 ESB. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento Connector zip file can be downloaded from [here](https://storepreview.wso2.com/store/assets/esbconnector/d293fcf6-09e7-4194-a8cd-00f77d174ac5). Go to the link and click the 'download connector' button.